# madgwick/ mahony Axes convention

Tags: accelerometer, quaternions, device-orientation, magnetometer

I have problem which mahony/ madgwick implementation

Could someone say something about that

[MPU-9250](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9B2v.png)

MadgwickQuaternionUpdate(ax, ay, az, gx, gy, gz, my, mx, mz);

and another example

[BNO-055](http://api.ning.com/files/4Epf-T61UHP41R5kTSFUGZGG6Y5QUaIJsZX7p6NHlqqaLunj1GGg5sE1roq0ssP4yS7Sp*7jmI2vr8P5N561hYwSloZoWx76/BNO055.jpg)

MadgwickQuaternionUpdate(ax, ay, az, gx, gy, gz, mx, my, mz);

code comes from github user kriswiner

in first example Z axis is negated and it is +mz in function.

in second example Z axis is normal and it is +mz in function.

I think one is bad?
Which ones is bad?

Comment: What do you mean by 'bad'?

Comment: In case 1, and in case 2 magnetometer Z axis are different.
But the function that is called is almost the same (the same mz parameter)
In my opinion function in one case should be called witch -mz ? or I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In MPU9xxx magnetometer is physically separated from acc/gyro. So, axes are different. Just look on picture from datasheet:[image]

Z axis is mirrored, X and Y are swaped.